# ASP.NET Core 5.0 After IF Clauses, IFrame is not accepted

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

The most hilarious error ever. I'm just copying iframe tag from the yandex or any other code, IDE shows red line under iframe and it doesnt see it as html tag WHY IS THIS HAPPENING GUYS? PLEASE HELP

[image: Why?]

Comment: You don't show us all the code, their could be errors to the right that we don't see. Furthermore, assuming that this is Visual Studio: the VS Razor editor is sometimes a bit buggy. If the code **runs** fine, then try making a report to the VS team. In any way complaining about it here or calling it "hilarious" will not solve it.

Comment: Hi @Mertcan, please share your code instead of picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax wrong. Try this (I have added else if assuming you have more conditions):

```
@if(String.Equals(selectedMap, "Google Maps"))
{
    <iframe src="" />
}
else if (condition)
{
    <iframe src="" />
}
```